# .NET Web Service works only on localhost

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, localhost

I'm facing a rather strange issue which I can't address. I have written my own web service using WCF using Visual Studio. Then, I created a Windows Service project. At least, I installed it with `installutil` and everything worked fine. I can access it at `http://localhost:port/etc`.

Now, I would like to expose it on a different IP address. So I changed the `App.config` file putting this:

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/example/" />
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.111:1111/example/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

I tried also this:

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.111:1111/example/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

But none of them works. When I start the service an error dialog is shown to me telling that the service has immediately stopped.

May someone help me?

**UPDATE**

I changed the account for the service installer to `NetworkService` and now I'm getting the error:

```
Error 5: Access is denied
```

Some hints?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: try running the WCF with the new address in an console app first, this way you can debug a lot easier. If this is running fine you probably have security issues, try running the service under another account. And check the event log for a detailed error message to post here.

Comment: Check the firewall, check that the port is actually open `netstat -a`, etc.

Comment: blocked firewall should not take the service down

Comment: I changed the user to `NetworkService` and now when I start the service it shows me another error message: `Error 5: Access is denied`.  Then, do have some hints?

Comment: Your ip is wrong, it should be 192.168.111.111, not 1111

Comment: I wrote it wrong here, it is correct and it is 192.168.1.111. Thanks for your comment, I fix my typo

Comment: `Access is denied`: then I guess your initial service account was a better choice. try running the stuff in a console app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried to listen http://0.0.0.0:1111 it should listen on all PC interfaces on port 1111

Comment: actually it worked for me...but I can't understand why 0.0.0.0 is ok and 192.168.1.111 was not!